# How to redirect path with querystring to another path

Tags: iis

I have a path like this:

```
/folder?cat=1&name=Test
```

I need a IIS rule that redirect everything to:

```
/folder/Test/1
```

I used this but it doesn't work:

```
<rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="cat=(.*)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="name=(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/folder/{C:1}/{C:2}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this rule:

```
 <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/folder$" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="cat=(.*)\&amp;name=(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="folder/{C:2}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```

It is working on my side

[image]